# html.beginform missing from one property in mvc4 razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this razor view:

```
@using System.Globalization
@using Order.Models
@model CartIndexViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Shopping Cart";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th class="text-right">Price</th>
                <th class="text-right">Subtotal</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var m in Model.Cart.Items)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="text-center">@m.Quantity</td>
                        <td class="text-left">@m.Item.Name</td>
                        <td class="text-right">@m.Item.Price.ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))</td>
                        <td class="text-right">@((m.Quantity * m.Item.Price).ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB")))</td>
                        <td>
                            @using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveFromCart", "Cart"))
                            {
                                @Html.Hidden("ItemId", m.Item.Id)
                                @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.ReturnUrl)
                                <input class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit" value="Remove"/>
                            }
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" class="text-right">Total:</td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                        @Model.Cart.ComputeTotalValue().ToString("C", new CultureInfo("en-GB"))
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@Model.ReturnUrl">Back to Menu</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I'm testing the 'Remove Item' functionality but I'm missing the

> @using (Html.BeginForm("RemoveFromCart", "Cart"))

from the first item in the cart. I have multiple items for test but for some reason the 1st item each time is missing the html.beginform functionality.
For example, viewing the source I have this for the 1st item:

[image]

Compared to the first image I have this structure for the second item:

[image]

What are we missing here, why each time the first item is missing the form block?

Comment: I'm not aware of any specific MVC issues but my understanding is the nested forms aren't really supported in HTML, I'm wondering if this scenario is supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure specifically why this is happening but nested form tags are not valid in HTML so my guess is that this scenario is unsupported in MVC as well. It is still strange that it would fail on the first item and not the others though.

I'm sure there are workarounds, you could build the inner tag manually, however given that it won't likely post back correctly I'm thinking you may want to try a different approach here.

I'd suggest either removing the outer form tag completely, or using a different mechanism for the posts, for example using an action link combined with JavaScript to avoid the form mechanism for this all together.